# Ethernet Magnetics Polarity Swapping

Tags: transformer, ethernet, magnetics, phy, rj45

Can I on the same pair (for Example A) to swap polarity on opposite side of transformer/magnetics?
[image]

Update 1: Currently i use cross-over method to make lanes shorted and more easy to layout.
[image: Cross-Over]

Update 2: Magnetics signal flow when pairs are swapped inside magnetics
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do this but, what do you hope to fix or achieve?

Comment: @Andyaka can be useful for layout when you have crossed lanes, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oYSH.jpg).

Comment: It depends on the Ethernet devices. It is possible that some devices work and some don't.

Comment: Exactly i have crossed lanes and want to achieve less lengh.I will post here the layout i have currently

Comment: Check image in Update 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any congestion problems here; you have numerous free routing options:

[image]

Not to mention, there's no penalty for using vias here, and you'd only need a maximum of one via per line to do any possible permutation of the pads in question (assuming there's adequate routing room on the opposite layer, or inner layers).

Length matching on this scale is utterly irrelevant for 10/100; length mismatch and stub length of many cm is permissible without signal quality degradation.  You can still do it [length matching] if you're feeling cute about it and have the free space.

Length matching also means a lot less in the non-plane-backed media region (there's no plane there, right..?): instead, the wider footprint of the accordion-ed trace just unbalances the pair, making one lead look wider, exposing it slightly more in the common mode.

Swapping transformers, and swapping polarities (on both sides), is acceptable anywhere the transformers are symmetrical.  (They might not be perfectly symmetrical in some more specialty/limited magnetics packages, but most use identical transformers and CMCs.)  Transformers are typically labeled for your convenience (TX/RX, P/N), but these are largely just convention.

"Swapping transformers", meaning: connecting PHY `TX_P/N` to magnetics `RX_P/N` and magnetics `RD_P/N` to connector `TD_P/N`, and vice versa.

"Swapping polarities", meaning: connecting PHY `TX_P` and `RX_P` to magnetics `TX_N` and `RX_N`, and connecting magnetics `TD_N` and `RD_N` to connector `TD_P` and `RD_P`, and vice versa.  Such a swap can be done for neither, just TX, just RX, or both; doesn't matter, as long as the polarity is swapped back on the opposite side.

Swapping polarities of the line itself (so `TX_P` reaches `TD_N` and vice versa) changes the signaling, and so depends on the signaling itself.

Likewise, swapping pairs (RX for TX) without swapping them back, changes the order of RX and TX entirely.

Both may be tolerated, due to polarity detection and auto-MDIX, but for "best practices" you may still prefer keeping them as-labeled.

---

If you are finding any of these swapping ideas confusing, my best advice is to just *not do it*, stick to the part drawings as labeled, and use vias.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, this helped a lot.

Comment: Hi there @RaduG. -- if this has answered your question, consider upvoting and accepting as answered.  These actions are the Stack version of thanking, moreso than comments are (but I also appreciate the comment :) ).

Answer (score 0):

For 100Base-TX and 1000Base-TX, neither the cable nor the PHY cares about the polarity. MLT-3 (100Base-) and PAM-5 (1000Base-) encoding generate the same signal regardless.

If your Ethernet link is one of the above then swapping pair polarities shouldn't be a problem; otherwise, don't swap.

Comment: How do you know MLT-3 is even used here and it does not care about the polarity? It might be a 10M PHY and it might care about the polarity. The link pulses may be polarity sensitive in order to autonegotiate the actual link up.

Comment: @Justme you're right. My assumption was 100Base-TX. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Well the LAN8720 does support both 10M and 100M, and it does support auto-MDIX and automatic polarity detection and correction, so your answer may still hold.

Comment: Exactly, LAN8720A is claiming both are supported. But i have doubts about magnetics.

Comment: @RaduG. why (or what kind of doubts) do you have?

Comment: Check update 2,this is my concern, how signal flow inside magnetics.
Maybe i need to get back to theory.